# C++ Store Function without Argument

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

Say that you define a callback function as such:

```
typedef std::function<void(float)> Callback;
```

And you have a function as such:

```
void ImAFunction(float a)
{
    //Do something with a
}
```

Is there a way to be able to store a function without an argument then pass one to it at a later time?

Such as this:

```
//Define the Callback storage
Callback storage;

storage = std::bind(ImAFunction, this);

//Do some things

storage(5);
```

This wont work which I explain with some of my real code below.

I can get close to what I wan't if I bind the value in with the std::bind function. Such as:

```
//Change
//storage = std::bind(ImAFunction, this);
storage = std::bind(ImAFunction, this, 5.0); //5.0 is a float passed
```

This works but when I go to pass a value through the function the outcome is whatever I set it to before:

```
storage(100); //Output is still 5
```

I am basing the fact that I think this is possible on this article.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

It doesn't use the function or bind functions but it does pass pointer arguments and performs exactly what I need. The reason I don't just skip the bind function is because I am trying to store the function in a class (private) and I can't store it if it's a template because it's created with the class.

The error produced above comes from this code:

```
struct BindInfo {
    Callback keyCallback;
    int bindType;
    bool isDown;
    bool held;
    std::string name;
};

template <class T1>
void bindEvent(int bindType, T1* keydownObj, void(T1::*keydownF)(float), std::string name)
{
    BindInfo newKeyInfo = { std::bind(keydownF, keydownObj), bindType, false, false, name };

    inputBindings.insert(std::pair<int, BindInfo>(BIND_NULL, newKeyInfo));
};
```

The error is:

```
No viable conversion from '__bind<void(Main::*&)(float), Main *&>' to 'Callback' (aka 'function<void (float)>'
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be looking for `std::bind(ImAFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a placeholder for an unbound argument:

```
std::bind(&Main::ImAFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

If you find that a bit of a mouthful, a lambda might be more readable:

```
[this](float a){ImAFunction(a);}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a function pointer. While I don't have a lot of experience using them in C++ I have used them in C so: Yes, it is possible. Perhaps something like this:

```
void (*IAmAFunctionPointer)(float) = &IAmAFunction;
```

The best way to think about that line is, that IAmAFunctionPointer is a pointer (hence the *), it returns a void, and takes a float. Then later:

```
float a = 5;
IAmAFunctionPointer(a);
```

You could even design it so that the callback function is passed into the method (I assume this is what you're looking for).

```
    void DoStuffThenCallback(float a, void (*callback)(float))
    {
     //DoStuff
     callback(a);
    }
```

further reading: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: The problem with this is I won't know the class and the function so it would have to be a template then to be able to store it. I can't store a template object.